# Haskell: Split a list by a list of indices

Tags: haskell, split, functional-programming

I am new to functional programming and learning Haskell. I have a list of indices and a list of elements that I want to split according to the list of indices (sorted in increasing order).

```
splitByIndices :: [a] -> [Int] -> [[a]]
```

I am thinking of `take indexlist[n]` and `drop indexlist[n-1]` but do not know how to implement it with `foldl`. Please help! Thanks!

Example:

```
splitByIndices [1,2,3,4,5] [1,2] = [1],[2],[3,4,5]
```

Comment: I'd recurse on `splitAt`

Comment: That's not all. What do you do when `splitByIndices [] [1,2]`?

Comment: @SassaNF Oh yeah, I should consider that boundary condition as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
splitByIndices :: [a] -> [Int] -> [[a]]
splitByIndices xs is = go xs (zipWith subtract (0:is) is) where
    go [] _      = []
    go xs (i:is) = let (a, b) = splitAt i xs in a : go b is
    go xs _      = [xs]
```

This of course produces incorrect results when the indices aren't strictly increasing. You could enforce this condition with:

```
import Data.List

enforce :: [Int] -> [Int]
enforce = map head . group . sort
```

and then you can use `enforce is` instead of `is`.

Answer (score 3):

The [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package offers this by the name [`splitPlaces`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v%3asplitPlaces).

Comment: no it's not. `splitPlaces` does split by chunk sizes, not indices.

Comment: @neizod Good point. One would have to use `zipWith (-) indices (0:indices) ++ [maxBound]` or similar to convert `indices` to chunk sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this with foldr, it is kind of complicated:

```
splitByIndices :: [String] -> [Int] -> [[String]]
splitByIndices input indexlist = foldr (\elem acc -> [fst $ splitAt elem $ head acc] ++ [snd $ splitAt elem $ head acc] ++ (tail acc)) [input] indexlist
```

Comment: well done. You can match head and tail directly in `acc`, and you won't need splitAt. `splitByIndices xs ix = foldr (\i (x:xs) -> (take i x):(drop i x):xs) [xs] ix` - but there are same questions about empty `xs`. What are you meant to produce if `xs` is even shorter than `ix`? What are you meant to produce if `ix` contains repeating indices? What are you meant to produce if the indices are not in ascending order?